# How to register a COM (Component Object Model) in Windows? (for Icon Overlay Handler)

Tags: c++, windows, com

I am quite inexperienced with COM objects, following is what I did:

- In C++, I created a class which extend IUnknow and implements QueryInterface, AddRef and Release.
- Extend IShellIconOverlayIdentifier and implements the 3 methods inside.
- Export the class with __declspec(dllexport)
- The DLL is compiled with MSVC2015 64 bits. (working on a windows7 64bits).

Now comes the difficult part:

How to make windows to link/use the DLL:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127455(v=vs.85).aspx Explain how to register the Overlay handler, but not how to register the COM object. I made a few tries, but after windows restart, nothing happens.

**How to register and how to check if registered a COM dll?**

**Is there compilation restrictions like compiler/architecture?**

EDITED Simplified:

It seem that I had a very incomplete vision of COM implementation, and in order to register the COM object, 2 directions are possible:

- Register manually the object in the register, which is a nightmare.
- Implement DllRegisterServer and DllUnregisterServer: which is a nightmare also.

To simplify the problem, I removed everything else up to having only those 2 functions:

```
STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
{
    return NOERROR;
}

STDAPI DllUnregisterServer(void)
{
    return NOERROR;
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not exported to the DLL, (as no __declspec(dllexport) is specified). As soon as I try to add this declaration, the compiler complain and no DLL is generated.

SOLUTION STEP 1:

> Olectl.h is very very bad and avoid DllRegisterServer to be exported.

Comment: See here; http://stackoverflow.com/a/5665927/3747990; if the COM dll is correctly built etc. `regsvr32` can be used to register the objects.

Comment: @Niall: "DllRegisterServer was not found", which mean "The specified Dll name is not a .dll or .ocx file. For example, typing regsvr32 wjview.exe generates this error message." I assume MSVC2015 64bit dll is not supported

Comment: No, they are all supported. Do you export the function named `DllRegisterServer` from the dll? Given the error, at least not properly. It is easiest to use the wizard in VS2015 and generate an "ATL COM object" project, it lays down all the boiler plate code. Then add a "COM object" to the project (from the menus or right click on the project and add it from there).

Comment: @Niall: That actually make sense: I did not implemented this function at all.

Comment: The 3rd bullet is where you went wrong.  A very basic premise of COM is that you never expose a class, only ever an interface.  What is missing is the class factory, an implementation of IClassFactory that knows how to create an object of your class.  That's boring plumbing that is easy to get wrong and always best left up to a library, ATL is the boilerplate approach.  Check [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects) to get a going quickly.

Comment: Any example without VS IDE? I mean pure C++ code.

Comment: I guess your are trying ATL. Try to add a Simple Component to your ATL project. And Add method to the Interface. VS will do the register job for you after build. If you want to register the dll manually, use regsvr32. You can find you ProgID in windows registry.

Comment: The problem is with this DllRegisterServer function, which cannot be declared as "DllExport" and, thus, is not exported.

Comment: Most likely, `DllRegisterServer` got exported with a decorated name. Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to verify. Use .DEF file to export with undecorated name. Note that you'd also need to export `DllGetClassObject` and `DllCanUnloadNow` (and it would be wise to export `DllUnregisterServer`, to reverse the effects of `DllRegisterServer`). On the other hand, you do *not* need to export your classes (it's harmless, but completely pointless).

Comment: `DllGetClassObject` must create and return an instance of the class factory, *not* the actual COM object. The latter is obtained via `IClassFactory::CreateInstance`

Comment: I created the .cpp, with `DllRegisterServer`, `DllUnregisterServer` ... When I do not set EXPORTDLL, they do not export and the DLL claim: "DllRegisterServer was not found". If I set EXPORTDLL, the compiler claim "redefinition; different linkage"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a `COM` object manually (without wizard), following steps are required:

- Implement `DllGetClassObject` & `DllCanUnloadNow`
- Implement Factory extending `IClassFactory`
- Implement the Target class, extending `IUknown`
- Register the `COM` in the registry
- [optional] implement `DllRegisterServe`r & `DllUnregisterServer` to make registry easier.

**Implements DllGetClassObject & DllCanUnloadNow**

Those are the only exported to the DLL functions:

```
STDAPI DllGetClassObject(_In_ REFCLSID rclsid, _In_ REFIID riid, _Outptr_ LPVOID * ppObject)
STDAPI DllCanUnloadNow(void)
```

DllGetClassObject, if the provided `rclsid` is the `TargetClassCLSID` and `riid` is the `FactoryCLSID, it creates and return a Factory object.

DllCanUnloadNow return if the DLL is in use (`S_OK`) or not, in which case the user/client may unload the DLL (`S_FALSE`).

The problem is, the definition do not allows to add `__declspec(dllexport)` due probably to some Microsoft monopol directive to make VS "mandatory".

To export them, just add before

```
#pragma comment( linker, "/export:DllGetClassObject,PRIVATE" )
#pragma comment( linker, "/export:DllCanUnloadNow,PRIVATE" )
//TODO: make this cross-compiler compatible?
```

**Implementing the Factory**

Implements `AddRef` and `Release`: they maintain how many client/users are currently using this Factory object. AddRef increment it by 1, Release decrements it by 1. As soon as the number is 0, `Release`may auto delete itself.

Implements `QueryInterface` which return if `riid`is the FactoryCLSID.

Implements `CreateInstance`, which return an instance of the TargetObject if riid match TargetClassCLSID

**Implementing the Target Class**

Again, we have to implements AddRef, Release and QueryInterface, but for the final class this time.

In my case, this Target class extends IShellIconOverlayIdentifier.

**Register the COM object into the OS registry**

After generating the dll, several registry need to be set. Some of them are linked together, so adding one may automatically add another.

```
HKEY_CLASS_ROOT::CLSID::<Add Here>
HKEY_CLASS_ROOT::Wow6432Node::CLSID::<Add Here>
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE::SOFTWARE::Classes::CLSID::<Add Here>
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE::SOFTWARE::Classes::Wow6432Node::CLSID::<Add Here>
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE::SOFTWARE::Wow6432Node::Classes::CLSID::<Add Here>
```

Content to add is:

- Create a key: name=`{TargetClassCLSID}`, value=`<Any app name>`
- Create a sub-key: name=`InProcServer32`, value=`<link to your dll>`
- Create a sub-string of InProcServer32: name=`ThreadingModel`, value=`Apartment`

//TODO: probably there are other alternatives, to better understand what that mean.

In my case, I had to register some more registers for the IconHandler:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE::SOFTWARE::Microsoft::Windows::CurrentVersion::Explorer::ShellIconOverlayIdentifier::<Overlay here>
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE::SOFTWARE::Microsoft::Windows::CurrentVersion::ShellExtensions::Aproved::<new entry here>
```

Where the overlay entry is a key: name=`<Any app name>`, value=`<TargetClassCLSID>`

The new entry is a string value which name=`<TargetClassCLSID>`and value=`Any app name`

Those values need also to be in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE::SOFTWARE::Wow6432Node::Microsoft::Windows....
```